# vb .net rename files based in two listbox within same position

Tags: vb.net

I have a listbox with filenames (without extension).
I need to rename those files to the name with the same value from `SelectedIndex` in `listbox2` but I'm having some trouble.

My code to rename is working (tested with one simple filename), but I can't get the same "position" from `listbox1` and get the value from `listbox2` to rename the file:

```
For Each oItem In ListBox1.Items
    My.Computer.FileSystem.RenameFile(TextBox1.Text & oItem & ".png", "SecondTest.txt")
Next oItem
```

Since `oItem` doesn't have the value of `SelectedIndex`, I can't get the value from the same `SelectedIndex` from ListBox2.

Can someone help me please?

Comment: Enumerate with `For i as Integer = 0 to ListBox1.Items.Count - 1` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not use `For Each` here as you need the index. you can write this way:

```
Dim n as Integer = ListBox1.Items.Count
For i = 0 to n - 1
    Dim oItem as String = ListBox1.Items(i), item2 as String = ListBox2.Items(i)
    My.Computer.FileSystem.RenameFile(TextBox1.Text & oItem & ".png", item2)
Next
```

the code inside RenameFile should be written based on what you want. (the item2 is the associated item from second listbox)